# vertical spacing between fillin in exam

Tags: exam

I am using an exam package and the following code

```
\fillin[$P(X\le6)-P(X\le3)$][3.7in]
```

but there is an vertical space issue which I could not find a solution for it between the equation and the horizontal line. Please see the picture
[image]

Comment: Putting `\setlength\answerclearance{1.25ex}` in your document's preamble should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `\fillin[\raisebox{.5ex}{$P(X\le6)-P(X\le3)$}][3.7in]` as in this example:

```
\begin{questions}
\question \fillin[\raisebox{.5ex}{$P(X\le6)-P(X\le3)$}][2in] this is the question.
\end{questions}
```

[image]

But adding too much of a vertical space can make the answer ugly, so be cautious  when adding such a space.

Another (better) option is to use bold math (via `\usepackage{bm}`):

```
\fillin[$\bm{P(X\le6)-P(X\le3)}$][2in]
```

which outputs this (better) result:

[image]