# Extra vertical padding at top of solution environment

Tags: spacing, formatting, vertical-alignment, multicol, exam

I have noticed extra padding at top of my solution environment (using the `exam` class) especially if you use `multicols` inside of the solution environment:

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=.75 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,color,srcltx,enumitem,bm,cancel}
\usepackage{multicol}

%Lengthens \fillin answer lines and raises text above the line so text isn't cut off by the answer line, see documentation http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/exam/examdoc.pdf and this question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/352246/vertical-spacing-between-fillin-in-exam 
\setlength\fillinlinelength{6.5cm}
\setlength\answerclearance{1.25ex}

%Answerline to right of question, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82152/answerline-to-the-right-of-a-question
\usepackage{letltxmacro}% http://ctan.org/pkg/letltxmacro
\usepackage{xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}% <cmd>
  {\par\nobreak\vskip\answerskip}% <search>
  {\leaders\hbox{\hskip0.2em .\hskip0.2em}\hskip 0pt plus 1filll}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\xpatchcmd{\answerline}{\fi \par}{\fi}{}{}% Remove line break after \answerline
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro{\oldanswerline}{\answerline}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\answerline}{s o}{%
  \begingroup
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\def\@queslevel{\relax}}% \answerline*
    {}% \answerline
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\oldanswerline[{}]}% \answerline
    {\oldanswerline[#2]}% \answerline[..]
  \endgroup
}

\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\printanswers

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question Show that $f(x)=x+8$ and $g(y)=y-8$ are inverses.
\begin{solution}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{align*}
f(g(y))&=(y-8)+8 \\
&= y
\end{align*}
\columnbreak
\begin{align*}
g(f(x)) &= (x+8)-8 \\
&=x
\end{align*}
\end{multicols}
\end{solution}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Some notes:

- I think `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}` makes the problem
  worse, but I don't want to remove this as I like the 1.5 spacing
  throughout the rest of the document.
- Deleting the spaces / blank lines before and after `\columnbreak`
  helps, but then it causes the right column to be higher than the left
  column (why?)

Thanks!

---

**Edit:** Thanks to John Kormylo for the idea:

```
\begin{solution}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\multicolsep=0pt
...
\end{solution}
```

Is there a way to to take care of this globally in the preamble, or perhaps define a new solution environment (like `solution*`?), so I don't have to remember to write it for every solution environment?

Comment: This is the same problem addressed here:" [Spurious space above `align` environment at top of page/`minipage`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/36954)

Comment: You can set \abovedisplayskip=0pt and \belowdisplayskip=0pt locally (inside solution).  You also might try \multicolsep=0pt.

Comment: Hi Barbara, I tried the `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd\start@align{%
  \if@minipage\kern-\topskip\kern-\abovedisplayskip\fi
}{}{}
\makeatother` but it had no effect on the solution environment. Changing the word `minipage` to `solution` didn't work either.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the tip! Is there any way to take care of this globally in the preamble, so I don't have to remember to write it for every solution environment?

Comment: Just bumping this topic. Is there a way to define a new solution environment (maybe solution*?) macro in the form

\begin{solution}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\multicolsep=0pt
...
\end{solution}